# Angularjs 1.5 component modal with callback function that is called multiple times by embedded Object in IE11 not updating Angular binding

Tags: angularjs, binding, callback, angularjs-components, embedded-object

In IE 11, I have an Angularjs 1.5 modal component as below. The modal opens and on render event it calls a function outside of the angular app with a callback function contained in this component. This outside function initiates a install process which kicks off an embedded object as shown below and this then periodically calls the callback function.

The issue I am having is the binding is not being updated in the template on each callback function called from the embedded object call. The console.log is executed and i can see the message in the console.
The binding is initially updated with 'starting process' so binding is correct

```
<span ng-bind="$ctrl.messages[$ctrl.messages.length - 1]"></span>
```

I tried calling scope.apply as below but nothing happens. Only when the initiateprocess is completed, the binding is then updated with the last message shown from the final callback call. So the initiateprocess function is blocking the binding but no blocking the console.log's

is this the correct way to handle multiple callbacks and updating bindings

```
  angular.module('components')
  .component('testModal', {
    bindings:{
      modalInstance: '<',
      resolve: '=',
      dismiss: '&',
      close: '&'
    },
    controller: TestController,
    templateUrl: 'scripts/components/TestModal.html'
});

TestController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function TestController($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.$onInit = function(){
    ctrl.messages = [];
    ctrl.messages.push('starting process');
  };

  ctrl.modalInstance.rendered.then(function(){
    CallVanillaJSFunction(callback); 
  });

  function callback(message){
    ctrl.messages.push(message);
    console.log(ctrl.messages[ctrl.messages.length - 1]);
    CheckScopeBeforeApply();
  }

  function CheckScopeBeforeApply() {
    if(!$scope.$$phase) {
      $scope.$apply();
      console.log('scope applied');
    }
  };

}
```

Vanilla Function

```
var globalCallback;

function CallVanillaJSFunction(callback){
    globalCallback = callback;
    var complete = initiateprocess();
    globalCallback(complete);
}
```

Embedded Object

```
<OBJECT ID="testObj" CLASS......
<SCRIPT language=javascript for=testObj event="OnEvent(message);">
      if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") != -1)
      {
         globalCallback(message);
      }
    </SCRIPT>
```

This question has been marked as duplicate but having looked at the duplicates I don't think it is the same. The global callback function can be called multiple times and the angular application does not know how many times it will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$timeout` service to force a browser tick:

```
  function callback(message){
    $timeout(function() {
       ctrl.messages.push(message);
       console.log(ctrl.messages[ctrl.messages.length - 1]);
    });
    ̶C̶h̶e̶c̶k̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶B̶e̶f̶o̶r̶e̶A̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶)̶;̶
  }
```

If the updates to the message occur all in the same browser tick, only the last update will be rendered. The `$timeout` service does both a framework digest cycle and a browser rendering cycle.

For more information, see [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg, that indeed does work for the case i had outlined before. However I have added more details of how the callback is being called by an object on the page and when I call $timeout now i get the digest error **Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress**

Comment: I updated the question. The function initiateprocess seems to be blocking the updating of the bindings, even though the callback in the embedded object logs to the console at the exact place the binding variable is changed